# Apache backend not able to find desired route

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Iam a beginner to php.

I have used XAMP to run my php backend on Apache server.
I have created a user table in my mysql database. Now I have made CRUD operations in my php backend in order to create a user, delete a user, update a user and read a user.

Now I have made routes in my **.htaccess** file.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule    ^not-found/?$    pages-404.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "not-found"

RewriteRule    ^api/addUser?$    _addUser.php    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^api/login?$    _loginUser.php    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^api/logout?$   _logoutUser.php    [NC,L]


ErrorDocument 404 /pages-404.php
```

I am sending post request via link `https://localhost/api/login/` to add a user in the database.

But I get this error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
    <p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
        error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.0.30 Server at localhost Port 443</address>
</body>

</html>
```

How ever If i try to send a post request directly to `https://localhost/api/_loginUser.php`. It runs successfully. Infact all the CRUD operations related to the tables present in my database work successfully like that.

But when I make their routes like this:

> ```
> RewriteRule    ^api/login?$    _loginUser.php    [NC,L]
> ```

in my .htaccess file.
They don't seem to work.

Now I can't seem to figure out what can be my problem with **.htaccess** file.

One solution was to modify the httpd.conf in the following part.

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But it also hasn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

are you giving access to a user to your database or your storing a visitor into the database? because if you are giving a user access to the database you can do it directly from phpmyadmin and edit the false section of the config.ini file and replace it with granted.on the other half storing a user into the database you can use the GET variable.

Comment: I have just created a user table. There are no validations on adding values in user table if that is what you are asking.